# Wordpress page doesn't load correctly unless you do a hard refresh

Tags: wordpress, pageload

So I changed the header and footer of my Wordpress theme and made some new pages but when I pushed them to production and had others view them the pages were showing up with no styling and the old header until they refreshed once or twice. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or need to change to fix this?

Comment: Google "web caching".

Comment: Have you ever had a solution for this problem? I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a caching plugin on your live server? Try disabling it when you push new updates. :)

Comment: I don't have any caching plugins. Another developer did however install a custom ABC testing framework for AB testing and I didn't know if that was maybe causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is either that you have a caching plugin like lazy load OR your jquery version is deprecated.

install "[Enable jQuery Migrate Helper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/)" plugin to find out. This plugin will tell you if there is a problem and will also provide you a temporary fix until you or your theme developer update to a higher version.